# Ternary operator for NumPy ndarray?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Does NumPy have a ternary operator? For instance, in R there is a vectorized `if-else` function:

```
> ifelse(1:10 < 3,"a","b")
 [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"
```

Is there anything equivalent in NumPy?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You are looking for [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> print numpy.where(numpy.arange(10) < 3, 'a', 'b')
['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

NumPy even has a generalization (that maps 0, 1, 2, etc. to values, instead of mapping only True and False): [`numpy.choose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html).

Comment: That is it. Thank you. Choose seems complicated but I will find a use for it somewhere.